# Adapt Webview height depending on the content inside

Tags: react-native

I am using Webview component in React Native to render HTML content. The problem I am facing is that I cannot make the height variable so it can adapt to any content it has.

```
return (
                <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                    <Header 
                        containerStyle={{
                            backgroundColor: 'white',
                            borderBottomColor: '#dee0e2',
                            borderBottomWidth: 1
                        }}
                        centerComponent={{ text: 'Noticia', style: { color: 'black' } }}
                        leftComponent={
                            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => navigate('homeScreen')}>
                                    <Text style={{color: '#4289f4'}}>Atrás</Text>  
                            </TouchableHighlight>
                        }
                    />
                    <ScrollView style={{padding: 5}}>
                        <View style={{flexDirection: 'column'}}>
                            <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 17, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{noticia[0].titulo}</Text>
                            <Image style={{width: '100%', height: 200, alignSelf: 'stretch', marginTop: 10}} source={{uri: noticia[0].imagen}} />  
                            <View style={{height: 200, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
                                <WebView
                                    source={{html: noticia[0].articulo}}
                                    scalesPageToFit={(Platform.OS === 'ios') ? false : true}
                                />
                            </View>
                        </View>



                    </ScrollView>
                </View>
              );
```

If I don't give the `<View>' that contents ' <Webview>' a height it does show me nothing. Tried already with`flex: 1` but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

In your parent view (root view directly under return()) style it as

```
height: '100%',
width: '100%'
```

It will adopt to any size screen.

Comment: This creates another scroll inside the <Webview>, and I just want to have one (the one defined in the code).

Comment: you can try: removing the `flex: 1` of the parent view, removing the `ScrollView` component altogether, or set `showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}` under the `ScrollView` component.